# access: compare date with numeric

Tags: ms-access-2013

Please help!

I want to compare two dates is Access, only problem is, one date is nummeric in the table like 20160316 and the other date is as date in table like #20-02-2016#
How can I calculate how many days are between these two dates?

Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Select 
    *, 
    DateDiff("d", CDate(Format([NumericDate], "@@@@\/@@\/@@")), [TrueDate])
From 
    YourTable1
```

or, for positive only differences:

```
Select 
    *, 
    Abs(DateDiff("d", CDate(Format([NumericDate], "@@@@\/@@\/@@")), [TrueDate]))
From 
    YourTable1
```